# Python GUI tool

Tags: python

I would like to create a GUI utility that can be used to retrieve information from UNIX logs in a production environment based on criteria entered by the user in the GUI tool.Not sure how I could do this though?Can either Perl,Python or Java be used to accomplish this?

Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Yes. They can all be used to achieve this.

Comment: Have a look at [PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide) - It's a set of python bindings for the Qt UI framework, and is LGPL

Answer (score 2):

Given the nature of your question, I'm guessing you don't know much about programming (or at least not much about the three languages you listed).  Since the answer is a simple and obvious yes, all three of those are general purpose languages and are fully capable of solving the problem you posed.

So if you're doing this as a fun project or a learning experience, then I'd recommend something simple to start out with such as Python + [EasyGui](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/index.html).  Python because IMO it's much easier to pick up than either of the other two.  And EasyGui because it's about as simple a GUI toolkit as I've seen for Python.

Now if you're being asked to do this under deadline, make sure to bake in a good week to a month or more of training depending upon your general comfort levels with things like installing software and programming in general.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of GUI tools for programming in Python.

http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming

http://www.wxpython.org/